# How to get the current config filename

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I want to be able to output the currently loaded config filename, is this possible?

I want to basically write out a log entry with the config filename so I know which config file loaded just to verify things.

Comment: Maybe this helps: "Set the Java system property -Dconfig.trace=loads to get output on stderr describing each file that is loaded." (https://github.com/typesafehub/config#debugging-your-configuration)